# Can I upload a Prawn generated PDF to Cloudinary on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary, prawn

I am generating a PDF file using the Prawn gem and trying to upload the file to Cloudinary, but I'm getting the error below.

```
"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `match' for #<Prawn::Document:0x00007f80b51545e0>>"
```

The code in Rails that I am using is as follows. It generates a file in the root directory but giving the aforementioned error:

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new
pdf.text "Hello World"
pdf.render_file "example.pdf"

result = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(pdf, options = {})
```

I have been able to upload the same file manually to Cloudinary. Is this programmatically possible within Rails? I cannot find any resources online one way or the other.

Cloudinary is working in my project just fine for image files.

***** UPDATE *****

The upload worked with the following code. It creates a pdf file in a directory, uploads it to Cloudinary, then deletes it:

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new
pdf.text "Hello World"
#creates file in directory
path = "public/system/temp_files/pdf_files/example.pdf"
pdf.render_file(path)
result = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(path)
#deletes file in directory
File.delete(path)
```

Comment: Have you looked at [cloudinary](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem) gem ?

Comment: I think so. I've been using Cloudinary pretty extensively for images, but it's my first time in dealing with PDFs. I'm wondering if I need to save it to a temp directory first then open and save it like I do for image upload... In any case, I cannot seem to find any relevant literature on PDFs and Cloudinary.

Comment: I don't think, that should be a problem, take a look at this api endpoint `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloud_name>/<resource_type>/upload` it mentions the [resouce_type](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload) if not mentioned it auto detects it. It should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: I changed the code to: result = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(pdf, :resource_type => 'auto'), but I'm still getting the same error. I'm pretty sure I cannot pass the pdf instance. I'll try to figure out how to make it a File instance. If anyone knows how to pdf.render_file and create a File new, please let me know.

Comment: I guess you should be using `raw` as the `resource_type`. And [these](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/204292392-Why-does-Cloudinary-reject-the-files-I-m-uploading-) are the only types that are not allowed for uploading. Also, make sure you don't upload some random `pdf` you download from **internet** they'll be flagged as spam and you might get the error **invalid_resource**. Sometimes you accounts needs to be enabled as well. Take a look at this [topic](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002273731-Not-able-to-upload-PDF-Files)